# MVC Controller and View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, gridview

How to use dataset in a controller to retrieve only the queried data and not all the data at once..can anyone help ?

Comment: Well, you normally use `Where` to filter the data. It's not clear what you've got at the moment - could you post your controller code, along with details of what you're observing vs what you expect to observe?

Comment: Currently i dont have the code. I use dataset so all data is getting dumped resulting in out of memory exception. IQueryable might be a solution to it but I have no idea how to use it

Comment: I suggest you read a LINQ tutorial before doing anything else then. This question is too broad at the moment.

Comment: Yup I can understand. I will post the code if possible.